# Java stored procedure or user-defined function could not call Java method

Tags: stored-procedures, db2, java

After I created a Java external stored procedure in DB2 as in my previous [question](https://dba.stackexchange.com/q/281068/219455), the call

```
call user1.send_mail(
   P_TO          => 'me@domain.com'
  ,P_CC          => NULL
  ,P_BCC         => NULL
  ,P_FROM        => 'me@domain.com'
  ,P_SUBJECT     => 'db2 java subject'
  ,P_TEXT_MSG    => 'db2 java test'
  ,P_HTML_MSG    => null
  ,P_ATTACH_NAME => null
  ,P_ATTACH_MIME => null
  ,P_ATTACH_BLOB => null
  ,P_SMTP_HOST   => 'domain.com'
  ,P_SMTP_PORT   => 465
  ,P_USER_NAME   => 'me@domain.com'
  ,P_PASSWORD    => 'secret');
```

fails it due to the following error:

> Java stored procedure or user-defined function "USER1.SEND_MAIL", specific name "SQL201208113215436" could not call Java method "send_mail", signature "(Ljava/lang/String".. SQLCODE=-4306, SQLSTATE=42724, DRIVER=3.68.61

I made sure that all parameters that have no default values receive non-`NULL` values. What else is necessary for this to work?

Update:

The `db2diag.log` file contains the following error message that I formatted for readability:

```
MESSAGE : java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: 
db2/smtp.send_mail(
Ljava/lang/String;
Ljava/lang/String;
Ljava/lang/String;
Ljava/lang/String;
Ljava/lang/String;
Ljava/lang/String;
Ljava/lang/String;
Ljava/lang/String;
Ljava/lang/String;
Ljava/sql/Blob;
Ljava/lang/String;
ILjava/lang/String;
Ljava/lang/String;)V
```

It is clear that the integer `P_SMTP_PORT` parameter of the Java method is missing between the 2nd and 3d last lines. It looks like it has been totally skipped, even though my SQL call includes this parameter. What does this mean? Also, what is the significance of the extra `I` in front of `Ljava` on the 2nd last line?

The JAR file is being registered from a C# application, using the following code:

```
using (var cmd = conn.CreateCommand())
{
    cmd.CommandText = "sqlj.db2_install_jar";
    cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
    cmd.Parameters.Add("blob", DB2Type.Blob).Value = File.ReadAllBytes(args[4]);
    cmd.Parameters.Add("jarname", DB2Type.VarChar, 257).Value = "javadb2";
    cmd.Parameters.Add("deploy", DB2Type.Integer).Value = 0;
    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();

    cmd.Parameters.Clear();
    cmd.CommandText = "SQLJ.REFRESH_CLASSES";
    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
}
```

I checked and made sure that the JAR file correctly trickles down to `C:\ProgramData\IBM\DB2\DB2COPY1\function\jar\USER1\JAVADB2.jar` after the code above runs, and that it is still in the correct format.

Answer (score 1):

As per Table 17. *SQL Data Types Mapped to Java Declarations* on p. 241 of *IBM DB2 10.5
for Linux, UNIX, and Windows Developing User-defined Routines (SQL and External)*, `BLOB` SQL data type maps to `java.sql.Blob` Java data type, not to `byte[]` that I had initially.